# Adding Jquery to aspx page when Master page has already declared Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

I need some help figuring out the best way to go about adding jquery code to my aspx file. We have a big front end solution in VS2008 using a master page. In the master page we have a ContentPlaceHolder where you can add stuff to the `<head>`, but the location of the place holder is above the code which declares the local path to jquery. Would I need to move the ContentPlaceHolder to a location below the jquery? If so, couldn't doing that cause some potential issues? I tried adding an additional ContentPlaceHolder under the script declaration tags, but that caused ViewState errors (I think having to do with code behind I added for my page to allow CSS3 for IE).

Here is the relevant code from the master file:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Class.Master.cs" Inherits="Company.Project.Masters.Class" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title><%# Page.Title %></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server" >
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="~/inc/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/inc/utils.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//some js stuff here
<style type="text/css">
        // some css stuff here
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='local/path/to/jquery' ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='local/path/to/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js") %>'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        //some jquery stuff here
        })
    }); 
</script>
</head>
```

Below is the code I have added to my page's .cs file to allow CSS3 elements to work in IE. This error looks like it is related to the ViewState error

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
       HtmlMeta xuac = new HtmlMeta();
        xuac.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
        xuac.Content = "IE=edge";
        Header.Controls.AddAt(0, xuac);
}
```

When I add a new ContentPlaceHolder in the MasterPage I get the error:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to all your points one by one.

You can have multiple content place holders in master page and you can refer to them in other pages. You should add a contentplaceholder right after jQuery script. And add content to this placeholder from child pages, it should not create any kind of problem.

Please share the view-state error you are getting on adding extra contentplaceholder. You can explore browser console for more information on view state problems.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question to include the error I get when adding a new contentplaceholder under the jQuery scripts.

Comment: Since you are adding xuac in each page load, so it is generating error (as viewstate got changed because of this). You should consider adding new controls only when required, e.g. if(!Page.IsPostBack) and so on.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference if that code is placed within if(!Page.IsPostBack) either way I get the "Failed to load viewstate" error upon postback.

Comment: I do not know why it is not working, ideally it should. Because after placing code in `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` will cause viewstate tree to be same in requests. Make the changes, load the page(normal GET) and then make a post (which we will be normal scenario in real life), you might be simply re-posting rather than starting afresh.